# Using CGAL with parameterized meshes

Tags: cgal

I have a mesh (close to polygon soup) with texture coordinates. I'd like to use CGAL for various operaitons on this mesh; most specifically the Naf_polyhedron class. I can "thicken" each triangle to make sure it's manifold and acceptable as a Naf, but I don't know how to carry the texture coordinates through the operations so they are preserved for vertices, and interpolated for cut edges.

Also, a single "point" may have multiple texture coordinates, as the texture coordinate is a function of both "face" and "point."

Are there examples or documentation for how to do this? Or does CGAL not support this in a mostly-built-in fashion?

Comment: Could you try to improve your question, it is not easy to understand what you want.

Comment: How do I use Nef_Polyhedron operations while preserving texture coordinates (parameterization) from the inputs to the outputs? For example, to implement a CSG operation on textured meshes? I'm starting to believe it can't be done.

Comment: As I said, you should click on the "edit" button below your question, to try to improve it.

Comment: I think my question is clear. What, specifically, is unclear about it? Which word is confusing? The specific problem statement is: "I don't know how to carry the texture coordinates through the operations so they are preserved for vertices, and interpolated for cut edges."